# Table with only vertical lines visible

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I need a way to show only the vertical lines in a table.

I've tried to add border-left and border-right, both with :1px solid #red;, to both the table and the separate td's. but it won't add the border color.

So what I'm looking for is an easy way to create these vertical lines.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use **border-collapse** on your `<table>` than **border-left** and **border-right** on your `<td>`.

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr { border: none; }
td {
  border-right: solid 1px #f00; 
  border-left: solid 1px #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you want to combine this with a table with rounded corners, you could also use

td:nth-child(odd){
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

instead.

Answer (score 3):

Expounding upon Simon's answer for those who want vertical lines within a table but not different columns. Note: you have to do it exactly as specified in his answer. The table itself needs border-collapse:collapse or multiple lines will show, the tr needs border:none or an outline will show, and the td border-left/right/top/bottom part is obvious.

```html
<html>
<head><style>
table {
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr {
 border:none;
}
th, td {
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding-top:0;
 padding-bottom:0;
}
.verticalSplit {
 border-top:none;
 border-bottom:none;
}
.verticalSplit:first-of-type {
 border-left:none;
}
.verticalSplit:last-of-type {
 border-right:none;
}
</style></head>
<body><table>
<tr><td>
 <table><tr>
  <td class="verticalSplit">A</td>
  <td class="verticalSplit">B</td>
 </tr></table></td>
<td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>D</td><td>E</td></tr>
</table></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, this code formatter sucks. I tried to keep it all somewhat neat while preventing scrollbars.