# Is it possible to give vertical lines separating columns in kable function in knitr?

Tags: html, css, r, markdown, knitr

I would like to give vertical lines between columns in the table being rendered. It shows on the R console. But not in the html document.

```
> kable(data.frame(1:10,11:20,21:30))


| X1.10| X11.20| X21.30|
|-----:|------:|------:|
|     1|     11|     21|
|     2|     12|     22|
|     3|     13|     23|
|     4|     14|     24|
|     5|     15|     25|
|     6|     16|     26|
|     7|     17|     27|
|     8|     18|     28|
|     9|     19|     29|
|    10|     20|     30|
```

[image]

I would also like to the shift the table to the left. I can make it another question if needed.

Comment: The issue is not in R, but in the CSS for the HTML output. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789947/table-with-only-vertical-lines-visible) for a possible styling strategy.

Comment: See the `align` argument of `kable` or my [`pandoc.table`](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#markdown-tables) function in the `pander` package for more features.

Comment: @daroczig align is for the data inside each column right? I wish to move the whole table to the left. Basically reduce the margins.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's an issue with the HTML css.

You can easily change the html css style in R markdown YAML as follow:

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  html_document:
     toc: true
     theme: united
---
```

You can read more about it [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) under *Output Options* section.

Comment: On the right direction, but probably not detailed enough to show how to define CSS rules for the left/right borders of `<td>`.